# How to compile liboauth for windows

Tags: windows

Anyone successfully compiled [liboauth](http://liboauth.sourceforge.net/) for Windows?

Any help here much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You need at least 0.9.3 to compile as you have tried.

```
version 0.9.3
 - yet more build-system fixes:
   - allow to override HASH_LIBS and CURL_LIBS using envoronment variables
   - include them in .pc and tests/Makefile.am
```

I use the following steps to make it work:

To do this you need MSYS/MINGW installed

1. Goto: http://www.gknw.de/mirror/curl/win32/
2. Download current curl-x.xx.x-ssl-sspi-zlib-static-bin-w32.zip
3. Open zip file read built.txt and find out which version of OpenSSL was used.
4. Extract libcurl.dll, libeay32.dll and libssl32.dll and install in
   mingw/bin directory
5. Goto the CURL homepage and download the matching curl-x.xx.x.zip file.
6. Open the zip file and move the include/curl directory into /mingw so
   it is at mingw/include/curl
7. Goto OpenSSL homepage and download the matching openssl-x.x.xy.tar.gz file.
8. Open the tar.gz and move the include/openssl directory into /mingw
9. Goto http://liboauth.sourceforge.net/ and download the current version
   (get 0.9.3 as a minimum)
10. from msys shell, run:

    ```
    env PKG_CONFIG=/bin/true ./configure --disable-static --disable-curl \
    CURL_LIBS=/mingw/bin/libcurl.dll HASH_LIBS="/mingw/bin/libeay32.dll \
    /mingw/bin/libssl32.dll" --prefix=/mingw
    ```
11. then:

    ```
    mingw32-make && mingw32-make check
    ```
12. Fingers crossed, it all compiles as it should.

    ```
    mingw32-make install
    ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio if you want. It works without modifications. You will also need libcurl or external cUrl executable.

You can build the libcurl as lib or incorporate it directly in your project.

Answer (score 0):

set up [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/), fire `./configure && make && make install`.

Comment: I tried 
CURL_CFLAGS="-I../curl-7.21.1/include" CURL_LIBS="../curl-7.21.1/lib/LIB-Release/libcurl.lib" HASH_CFLAGS="-I..
/openssl/include" HASH_LIBS="../openssl/ssleay32.lib  ../openssl/libeay32.lib" ./configure --disable-libcurl --enable-curl, but make is throwing "$ make
Makefile:171: *** missing separator.  Stop."

Comment: Makefile:171: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make sure you are using real tabs instead of spaces. A global search and replace for four-spaces should fix things up. but i doubt mingw environment. http://komisar.gin.by/mingw/index.html try this.